# Cretaing contratcs and asserts on portal users with accounts?

Tags: customer-portal

[image: creating contracts using account]

we don't have access on accounts for portal users. but for creating contracts we need account. Like the same way, For creating assets also we need(not a mandatory field) account for assets. how we can create contracts and assets if do not have access on accounts?

i am asking this query related to Customer portal users.....!

[image: creating assets using account]

Thanks in advance
S Kumaran

Comment: Could you please edit your original post to include screenshots of the Permission settings for the profile in question here. Thanks

Comment: HI @ cmmoutes13, Sorry for the delay, Please check now. i have updated with screen shorts.

Comment: I meant the permission setting for the profile. Not the error you receive while searching for a record. If you are unfamiliar with the permission settings that I am referring too. Please contact your system administrator and they will be able to help you with this issue.